# How to detect that a user installed an app with installType AVAILABLE

Tags: android-management-api

When an app is included in a policy with installType set to AVAILABLE (meaning the app is available to install) how can my EMM server detect that the user has installed the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possible ways to check if an app is installed on the device, [pub/sub](https://developers.google.com/android/management/notifications) or [enterprises.devices.get](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices/get). The device reports will list all apps installed on the device, not just the ones installed by the user. To pull app reports, you will need to include [`applicationReportsEnabled`](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.policies#statusreportingsettings) in your policy and wait for the device to sync with the server.

**Example policy:**

```
{
  "applications": [
    {
      "packageName": "com.adobe.reader",
      "installType": "AVAILABLE"
    }
  ],
"statusReportingSettings" : {
    "applicationReportsEnabled" : true
  },
  "debuggingFeaturesAllowed": true
}
```